# different http cookies between subdomains on CloudFront - S3 static site

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, cookies, httpcookie

We have a dynamic subdomain.

We use S3 static site =  AWS CloudFront + single S3 bucket + multiple subdomains via route53: `*.admin.our-domain.com`.

Our problem is that we need a separate **http cookie** for each subdomain.

How can we get it work?

Currently, all subdomains - for example `xxx.admin.our-domain.com` and `yyy.admin.our-domain.com` are sharing the same http cookie.

Adding code:

```
const subDomain = '.' + req.headers.origin.replace(/^https?:\/\//i, '');    
res.cookie(cookieKey, val, {
        domain: subDomain, # What I added according to the first comment
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 300 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    });
```

When I added the `domain: subDomain`, the cookie isn't being saved at all.

Comment: You can use the domain parameter in the cookies and specify specific subdomain.

Comment: I added it. But now seems like the cookie isn't saved.

Comment: @James Dean I updated the answer with more info about it